# Chrome Cron Job on Windows

Tags: php, windows, cron, task

I wonder if there are any way to setup a cron job on Google Chrome to be run every 2nd hour AND when the cron is complete, it automatically closes the window?

I currently have a cron job setup to go to my cron page using Windows Task Scheduler, although the window isn't closed so when I RDP the server it has quite a few windows opened using up RAM on the server.

So my real question is, how do I make Google Chrome close when the cron is complete?

Thanks in advance.
Regards, Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill a running process in windows using from the command line:

```
taskkill /IM <process name>
```

eg: `taskkill /IM chrome.exe` will close all running instance of google chrome.
So I guess you can run this command at the end of the task.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but this didn't work as the chrome window must be closed otherwise task scheduler doesn't consider the open chrome action to be complete. Any ideas? Regards, Tom.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Is the command I supplied not closing the Google chrome windows? Be a bit more clear please.

Comment: Exactly, I added the command to the action list in task scheduler after the action to open chrome and tried to run the task but it didn't close the window. I had to close the window manually and then the command you supplied me with was executed.

Comment: Just for testing schedule the close window cron to run 1 minute after the main cron job started and open the Google chrome window. And see if it closes the window or open chrome and run it in the command prompt and provide me with feedback. Use 'taskkill /IM chrome.exe'